# simple domain question

Tags: apache, apache-config, tomcat

Hi everyone I'm a new apache tomcat user I have question regarding seting up a domain name I'm kinda confused about that and how do I know what is my current domain name? can I change the domain name ? I looked into the apache documentations but it was not clear
Thank you in advance 
Lava

Comment: I'm using Apache tomcat 7.0.4

Comment: By my reading of this question it's more about domain registration and DNS records/hosting. Probably more appropriate to serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds a lot like it's asking about [domain name registration](https://serverfault.com/questions/175562/using-the-same-service-for-hosting-and-domain-name-registration) and [DNS hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744/hosting-your-own-dns) rather than anything tomcat specific.

Your current domain name is probably given to you by whoever hosts your server if you're using public address space. If it's a Unix/Linux box you can find out what that is (assuming things are configured sanely) from a shell using

```
hostname -A
```

If you only know the IP address you can make a [reverse lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) to find a DNS name that *probably* points back to your server.